Как работать с Spotify API на C#?
Хочу сделать загрузчик музыки из Spotify (Windows программа на WPF), суть программы такая - Пользователь вставляет ссылку на нужный трек и нажимает кнопку Скачать после чего музыка скачивается в заранее подготовленную папку, всё кроме загрузки самого трека сделал, но не представляю как сделать главную суть приложения, как мне кажется нужно использовать API спотифая, но я ни разу не работал с API и не представляю как это сделать, смотрел в инете там только с JS работают делая сайты.

Для API обычно нужен backend  если на Spotify его нельзя создать, то остается только один вариант прикидывать прямые ссылки к аудио если это не идет в разрез с планами.

Если вы ни разу не работали с Api, тогда вам ещё много чему стоит научиться. Для начала о Spotify. Вот ссылка на их официальный api, точнее, на документацию по их api. Вам стоит её изучить, что бы знать как с ней работать.
Но для начала рекомендую вам обучиться работе с api на примере лёгкого варианта. Я обычно рекомендую для начала попробовать реализовать этот крипто-api, т.к. он является достаточно легким и открытым.
Что нужно знать перед началом работы с api? В .net есть класс для работы с подобными вещами HttpClient, который позволит вам делать запросы на этим API. Далее вам стоит изучить, что вообще такое Http запрос, их вариации (HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut и т.д.) и в чём между ними разница. Следующий этап - это работа с json, потому что web сервера обмениваются (В большинстве случаем) между собой информацией в виде Http запросов, информация внутри каких передаётся в виде JSON объектов и подобные API не являются исключениями.
